# How would I select distinct (by unique month/year) from a generic list of dates?

Tags: c#, linq

So the distinct is based on unique Month/Year, not just one distinct month (so I would want January of 2011 and January of 2012 to be distinct)

```
 // Test set of data
        List<DateTime> CompleteListOfDates = new List<DateTime>();
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 5));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 3, 1));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 5, 1));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 5, 1));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1));
        CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 2, 1));

        List<DateTime> UniqueMonthYears = new List<DateTime>();

        /* need distinct list of DateTimes that are distinct by Month and Year and should be in UniqueMonthYears
         For example:
        new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)
        new DateTime(2011, 3, 1)
        new DateTime(2011, 5, 1)
        new DateTime(2012, 1, 1)
        new DateTime(2012, 2, 1)
        */
```

Comment: In addition to the numerous answers, you might find the DistinctBy function in MoreLINQ useful. http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List<DateTime> result = source
  .Select(d => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1))
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

---

Also useful:

```
ILookup<DateTime, Order> ordersByMonth = ordersSource
  .ToLookup(order => new DateTime(order.OrderDate.Year, order.OrderDate.Month, 1));
```

Comment: Excellent. Linq continues to impress me with the more I work with it

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own IEqualityComparer implementation and let Linq do the rest, like this:

```
// implement this
public class DateTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return x.Year == y.Year && x.Month == y.Month;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        return obj.Year * 100 + obj.Month;
    }
}

// use it like this
UniqueMonthYears = CompleteListOfDates.Distinct(new DateTimeComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not aware of an overload of Distinct that accepts an `IComparer<T>`. There is one that accepts `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: 1) Equals returns bool. 2) The implementation also needs `int GetHashCode(DateTime value)`.

Comment: As Anthony Pegram says you must implement GetHashCode and you must implement it correctly

Comment: I think I should write the code parts in VS and look for obvious errors before I post them...

Answer (score 2):

```
var uniqueMonthYears = CompleteListOfDates
                          .GroupBy(d => new{ d.Month, d.Year})
                          .Select(my => new DateTime(my.Key.Year, my.Key.Month, 1));
```

Will give you an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

Edit: David B's answer is better, but leaving this here as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest code I'd know of:

```
    List<DateTime> UniqueMonthYears = 
        CompleteListOfDates.Select(t => new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, 1))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Here's more structural but way less performant approach (for demo purpose only). What it give is the ability to set `string GetHash(Date)` and `Date CreateFromHash(string)` functions, thus making it more generic.

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<DateTime> CompleteListOfDates = new List<DateTime>();

            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 5));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 3, 1));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 5, 1));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2011, 5, 1));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1));
            CompleteListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 2, 1));

            List<DateTime> UniqueMonthYears = 
                CompleteListOfDates.Select(t => 
                    GetDateHash(t)).Distinct().Select(t => 
                        CreateFromDateHash(t)).ToList();


            MessageBox.Show(UniqueMonthYears.Count.ToString());
        }

        private static string GetDateHash(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("MMM-yyyy");
        }

        private static DateTime CreateFromDateHash(string hash)
        {
            return DateTime.Parse("1-" + hash);
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be demonstrating the use of a GetMonthYear function as you seem to suggest it does... You might want to tidy up your question a bit since you seem to have changed solution half way through writing...

Comment: Have you seen the period of time within which the answers were posted?:) I changed my mind lately as projection is much more transparent here.

Comment: Its nothing to do with comparison with other answers. Its that you start off suggesting a `GetMonthYear` function or using `DateTime.ToString("MM-YYYY")` and then you say "Here's the code" and the code is a third method again. It just implies currently that the code is a demonstration of the methods you had just described rather than a third solution. I'm happy to edit it up to be clearer if you want (I assume english is not your first language) but I always prefer to comment and let people tidy their answers up themselves.

Comment: Its ok. I'm relaxed and chilled. I just like trying to get answers to be better if there are any obvious things that can be improved. :) I like the nice genericness of your new answer though. :)

Comment: See the updated answer, and relax a bit. GetMonthYear is just one of the ways how the data can be 'distinctised', get me?. You can say - give me the second Tuesday fo each month or a full moon, which will use a side call - aint matter. Having GetHash/CreateFromHash generalises the approach.

Answer (score 1):

How about somthing like

```
completeListOfDates.Select(d => new {Year = d.Year, Month = d.Month}).Distinct()
```

Preserving the first occuring day part is essentially meaningless but you could do so like this.

```
completeListOfDates.Distinct(new YearMonthComparer());

private class YearMonthComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        if(x.Year != y.Year) return false;
        if(x.Month != y.Month) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + obj.Year.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + obj.Month.GetHashCode();
        reutrn hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aw! Everyone beat me to it. And LINQ questions are so much fun. ;-)

I didn't know how you wanted to select the unique date from the list, so instead of assuming you wanted to discard that, I used the First method in a subquery. Obviously you could change that using a sort of some kind as well as the predicate.

How about this then?

```cs
var UniqueMonthYears = (from date in CompleteListOfDates
                        let month = date.Month
                        let year = date.Year
                        let day = (CompleteListOfDates.First(d => d.Month == month && d.Year == year))
                        select day).Distinct();
```

Oh, and for bonus points... if you've not already, download Linqpad from http://www.linqpad.net/ You can try out this kind of stuff really easily with that.